# Using the werkzeug adapter example for google OAuth2 login of Authomatic+Flask results in user None

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, openid

I am learning to use Authomatic+Flask for OAuth2 login. I am running the example code provided.

I got Oauth2 working for FB. But on google, I don't understand why the user fields in the response come out as None.

I was already able to resolve the same issue on FB by tweaking the callback URI settings on FB dev/advanced settings. But on google, I can't seem to get the same thing to work. Played around with the user_info_scope settings as well but no joy.

Comment: Please add your current code, add versions of python packages, show returned data from OAuth providers

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable the Google+ API in the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project):

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your-app-id>/apiui/api
```

Comment: I think you should check new issues in your github repo. This solution is not good enough because this API is not unlimited.

Answer (score -1):

i agree with Peter.  I wrote up an example for this.  For Google specifically you need to authorize all the API's you want access to. See [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196887/google-and-twiter-return-empty-user-data-on-flask/27425845#27425845)